# Limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f(nx)x^\alpha dx$ for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, definite-integrals

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous function such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=1$ and $f(0)\neq 0$. I have to find limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f(nx)x^\alpha dx$. For $\alpha>-1$ by Stolz's theorem (after substitution $t=nx$) and  I got result $\frac{1}{\alpha+1}$ and for $\alpha=-1$ result is $-\infty$. Am I right? What in case $\alpha<-1$?
Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't that just $+\infty$? When $\alpha < -1$ the integral diverges (this is easy to see by looking at what happens in a neighbourhood of $0$) and the term $1/n^{\alpha + 1}$ also tends to infinity.

Comment: @ALive yes, +infinity